# How to send Custom tokens ERC20 fromWallet - ethers.js

Tags: myetherwallet, ethers.js

I have tried [this](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/121#issuecomment-367453923) solution and it worked but only if I use privateKey of the wallet which I used to create custom tokens but what if I want to send from B wallet to C wallet and when I am trying it, the transaction is happening but it's failing.

[Failed transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xdef1a8ada8edafcbf84c0013f6de51a56a97a86e0791858632b9d35d8a165454)

```
var contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, wallet);

var numberOfTokens = ethers.utils.parseUnits('10.0',numberOfDecimals);
var options = { gasLimit: 1500000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('1.0', 'gwei') };

contract.transferFrom(fromAddress, targetAddress,numberOfTokens,options).then(function (tx) { console.log(tx); });
```

thanks

Comment: Has the token owner added an `approve` for the tokens? They can't be transferred without his consent.

Comment: i am the owner but how to approve the transfer?

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you have to call an `approve` function of the ERC20 token smart contract that you want to transfer. You have to pass the amount that you want to transfer and the spender address to the `approve` function. Only then you will be able to make the actual transfer.